# Node.js: Response inside a promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, es6-promise

Anybody can me explain why this:

```
somePromise()
    .then(content => res.status(200).jsonp(content))
    .catch(err => res.status(500).send(err));
```

Is **not equivalent** to:

```
somePromise()
    .then(res.status(200).jsonp)
    .catch(res.status(500).send);
```

The first code is working well, the second not

*Thank you!*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the first example, `.jsonp` and `.send` are invoked as methods on the `res` object. This is necessary in order for them to work correctly; they must have access to the response object.

In the second example, you pass a reference to the `.jsonp` and `.send` functions, but when they are invoked they are not invoked as methods on `res`. This means that they do not have access to the response object, causing them to fail.

**UPDATE:**
Earlier, I had said you could modify the second example to use `.bind` and it should work:

```
somePromise()
    .then(res.status(200).jsonp.bind(res))
    .catch(res.status(500).send.bind(res));
```

That is not correct. What happens if you do the above is that the response will always have a 500 status code. That is because the execution goes like this:

- set `res.status` to 200
- bind `res` to `.jsonp`
- set `res.status` to 500.
- bind `res` to `.send`
- Later: invoke `.jsonp` or `.send`.  Both are bound to `res`, which has had its status code set to 500

Comment: I tried it but neither! 

Comment: yes, `.bind` neither works. And yes, maybe the first one is more beautiful heh! But I would like to know why don't works in another ways. `jsonp` and `send` are functions... Why don't work as a callback? 

Comment: @AralRoca - updated with what I'm pretty sure the problem is. Using `.bind` does preserve the `res` context, which is the main problem you were noticing, but there's a separate issue where `res` has its status code always set to 500. If you remove the `.status` call in both you should see `.bind` work

Comment: but issues like this is why the first example you have is better :)